# Rails, Devise: Same resource, different controller based on user type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I have a resource, say `Product`, which can be accessed by two different user classes: say `Customer` and `Admin`. There is no inheritance between these two.

I am using Devise for authentication:

```
# config/routes.rb

devises_for :customers
deviser_for :admins
```

I have these two controllers:

```
# app/controllers/customers/products_controller.rb

class Customers::ProductsController < ApplicationController
```

and

```
# app/controllers/admins/products_controller.rb

class Admins::ProductsController < ApplicationController
```

Now depending on who logs in (`Customer` or `Admin`), I want `products_path` to point to the corresponding controller. And I want to avoid having `customers_products_path` and `admins_products_path`, that's messy.

So I have setup my routes as such

```
# config/routes.rb

devise_scope :admin do
  resources :products, module: 'admins'
end

devise_scope :customer do
  resources :products, module: 'customers'
end
```

This doesn't work. When I login as a `Customer`, `products_path` still points to `Admins::ProductsController#index` as it is the first defined.

Any clue? What I want to do might simply be impossible without hacking.

**UPDATE**
According to [the code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/01f4a8f441a94c1450c156f7fa30ccd8ddc438db/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L317), it is not doable.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the best way to achieve that is to use routing constraints as such:

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :products, module: 'customers', constraints: CustomersConstraint.new
resources :products, module: 'admins', constraints: AdminsConstraint.new


# app/helpers/customers_constraint.rb

class CustomersConstraint
  def matches? request
    !!request.env["warden"].user(:customer)
  end
end


# app/helpers/admins_constraint.rb

class AdminsConstraint
  def matches? request
    !!request.env["warden"].user(:admin)
  end
end
```

I stored the constraint objects in the helper folder because I don't really know the best place to put them.

Thanks to [@crackofdusk](https://twitter.com/crackofdusk) for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

For this you will need to override the existing [after_sign_in_path_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L106) method of devise.  Put this in your `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

      if resource.class == Admin   

          '/your/path/for/admins'

      elsif resource.class == Customer

        '/your/path/for/customers'

      end 
end
```

**Note**: If you want to implement `previous_url` that was requested by user then you can use it like this:

```
  session[:previous_url] || 'your/path/for/admins'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want the trick to work for all `Product` related paths, not just the one after sign in. This is why I scope routes, i.e. to avoid conditional logic everywhere.

Comment: what u want exactly?... i didn't got u.

Comment: I want all CRUD path actions on the `Product` resource to point to a different controller depending on what class of user is signed in.

Comment: then u can do one thing... put a before filter in `products controller` and check for user type and act accordingly.

Comment: I want to do this at the routing level, hence the scopes. Different user class, different controller. Otherwise the `ProductController` will become a massive spaghetti bowl.

Comment: hav u definded scopes for that?