# How to have one resource in routes for namespace and root path altogether - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a custom admin panel in a namespace "admin".

I have resources "courses" within that namespace.

But I would also like a route to "courses" that is not in that namespace:

eg: BOTH `localhost:3000/admin/courses` AND `localhost:3000/courses`

It's OK if this requires different controllers.

My concern is that its not really DRY if i have both resources for the same route.

```
namespace admin do
   resources :courses
end
```

and just

```
resources :courses
```

Is there a way to have one resource be shared between namespace and without namespace, or is the example above the way to go?

Comment: After clarification, this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492370/rails-devise-same-resource-different-controller-based-on-user-type

Comment: Are you saying that both routes should go to the same pages?  Or is the action different for admin?

Comment: different pages,different controlllers,maybe same actions, and i wanted same routes if possible with same line of code. people below answered me :)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. If it were, it would be a duplicate of [this one instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695096/rails-routing-add-shallow-concern-to-root), however the question is slightly different. The author here is looking for a way to refactor to DRY things up. However maybe the question name could be rephrased ?

Comment: What would be an appropriate title for this then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh wait ! There's also the possibility to use [concerns](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) !

```
concern :shared_actions do
   resources :courses
   resources :something_else
end


namespace :admin do
   concerns :shared_actions
end
concerns :shared_actions # Will add it to the root namespace ^^
```

EDIT : apparently this is what [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695096/rails-routing-add-shallow-concern-to-root) also tried to do :D

Comment: let me try that and follow you up on it.

Comment: erm something with the syntax seems wrong,getting this error, and in my routes file i only have what you gave me above,syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
  namespace :admin, concerns :shared_actions

Comment: Was a missing colon ^^"

Comment: hmm still not working this is what i changed namespace :admin, concerns: [:shared_actions]
root 'welcome#index', concerns: :shared_actions, and i get this error,rake aborted!
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)

Comment: thank you scope worked but you miss something i will edit your post and mark this as working!yay!

Comment: Actually no need for scope. just writing `concerns :shared_actions` worked ^^

Comment: you were missing the do-end in the admin namespace, i edited it for you,its working thank you :D

Comment: TIL you can answer a question more than once on SE.

Comment: @CyrilDD Can you answer this if you know about it please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742416/routing-concerns-defining-different-param-for-resources

Answer (score 6):

I'm not really sure I understand what you mean, but

`namespace :something` is actually a shorthand for `scope :something, module: :something, as: :something`

- `scope :something` will add `/something/` as a URL prefix
- `scope module: :something` will add `/something` as a controller prefix (controllers will be fetched under `controlelrs/something/the_controller.rb`
- `scope as: :something` will add the `something` as a prefix for path helpers

Now it's totally fine to have both in your routes

```
resources :courses
# Will generate "/courses/", "/courses/new", "/courses/1/edit", ...
# And will point to `controllers/courses_controller.rb`

namespace :admin do
  resources :courses
end
# Will generate "/admin/courses/", "/admin/courses/new", "/admin/courses/1/edit", ...
# And will point to `controllers/admin/courses_controller.rb`
```

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: I agree that it is fine to have both in the routes, but isn't it cleaner to simply specify the scope and module? Which is exactly how the rails guide suggests to do it (at least to my understanding).

Comment: as i said jkeuhlen,i think you misunderstood what i want to do, i want to have a separate admin controller for admin/courses/ path and another controller for the front-end path /courses. with the syntax you guys give me all it does is point to admin/courses controller which is not want i want. I just asked if there is special syntax in routes.rb that can yield me routes for courses/ path and admin/courses/ path with one line of code instead of writing resources two time. understand now? is it possible?

Comment: I believe it depends on your personal taste. Personally, when I read `namespace :admin` it makes more sense to my mind than just reading `scope :admin, module: :admin, as: :asmin`

Comment: @jkeuhlen What the solution you are suggesting will do is create `courses_path` instead of `admin_courses_path` and will take it to admin controller always. Instead the OP needs to map to admin and a without scoped controller both using a single resource.

Comment: @CyrilDD Fair enough. Just curious! I'm here to learn as well :)

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou No it is not possible with just one line of code to handle both `/admin` and `/`. but the above code does exactly what you want., it doesn not point JUST add `/admin/resources` but also `/resources`. check the routes `rake:routes`

Comment: @Deep Yeah, I misunderstood the question. Asked OP to update to clarify and I'll remove mine momentarily since it isn't helpful.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou I believe there is no short way of doing that you will need to keep both the resources in your routes file. And it is necessary too to have that. Like in my application I have admin and frontend. And I have a slug attribute in courses. So in the admin side I have route like `/courses/1` and in front end I have `/courses/english-123245`, not displaying the `id` to frontend users instead displaying slug. So keeping the seperate helps in tasks like this.

Comment: thank you guys i believe you answered me what i wanted to know!thanks again!

Comment: @CyrilDD what is your thought of the DRY paradigm in this case? i mean obviously its duplicate code just in one case its under a namespace. syntax like resources :courses, namespaces: '/' , 'admin' ,wouldnt be a better approach without duplicating code?

Comment: Just reeeeeembered about concerns. See my other answer !